# Return two widgets from a getView methord

Tags: android

I am working in an android application and I want to implement a Gallery. And on my getView method now I return a Image View. In this method I want to return a button and an Image View. How can I do this.

Thanks in advance

This is ma code :

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 180));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);
        return imageView;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, you'll need to create a ViewGroup (LinearLayout, for example, but all layouts are ViewGroups) and place your ImageView and Button within this container. You will return the ViewGroup from your getView method.

Answer (score 1):

Use separate layout for list item with imageview and button widgets. return this view from adapter getView() method...

check this example for your requirement.[Custom adapter for listview](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter)